# Unable to append row through javascript function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to append a row to a table. And this is the code that i tried

```
function load() {
    for (var k = 0; k < 1; k++) {

        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("pID");
        var tableBody = document.getElementById("tBody");
        var table = document.getElementById('pTable');
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var tr = document.getElementById('RiskRow');

            tableBody.appendChild(tr);

            for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                var element1= document.getElementById('RiskTD');
                var element2= document.getElementById('severityTD');
                var element3= document.getElementById('mitigationTD');
                var element4= document.getElementById('contingencyTD');
                var element5= document.getElementById('riskStatusTD');
                tr.appendChild(element1);
                tr.appendChild(element2);
                tr.appendChild(element3);
                tr.appendChild(element4);
                tr.appendChild(element5);
            }

        }
        myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
    }
}
```

But this results in appending only one row. I need multiple rows to be added that follows the for loop. Im not sure where i stuck up.

Comment: you write in for statments: while k is smaller from 1.

Comment: You can't give the same ID to several elements. And you fill the row with elements you take elsewhere, so all the rows except the last one are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the redundant loops you have there (`var k = 0; k < 1` will always perform once...), the reason you're seeing this behavior is because you're trying to append the same element over and over. This will cause the element to be moved, rather than copied.

Have a look at **[`document.cloneNode`](https://devdocs.io/dom/node/clonenode)**